# How to find intersection of 2 dataframes based on multiple columns in spark/scala?

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, intersection

DF 1:

```
+---------+--------------+---------------+----------+-------------------+
|id       |           key|          tg   |created_at|          timestamp|           
+---------+--------------+---------------+----------+-------------------+
|device_id|    essentials|       template|1600269347|2020-09-21 19:08:05|              
|     test|         t_key|             t1|1599714939|2020-09-16 01:37:55|
|     test|         t_key|             t2|1600084857|2020-09-21 17:08:23|              
|device_id|    experiment|             t1|1599721314|2020-09-17 01:37:17|
|device_id|    experiment|             v1|1600228007|2020-09-21 18:07:53|
|device_id|    experiment|             c1|1605221085|2020-09-21 18:07:53|
+---------+--------------+---------------+----------+-------------------




DF 2:

 +---------+-------------+----------------+----------+-------------------+
|id        |          key|            tg  |created_at|          timestamp|
+---------+--------------+----------------+----------+-------------------+
|device_id|    essentials|        template|1526472602|2020-10-15 19:08:05|
|device_id|    experiment|              c1|1727784602|2020-10-10 01:37:17|
|device_id|    experiment|              x1|1728994202|2020-10-19 01:37:17|
|     test|            tk|               a|1728994202|2020-10-19 01:37:17|
+---------+--------------+----------------+----------+-------------------+
```

How to find the intersection of these 2 dataframes on the basis of these two columns "id" and "key".
Note: All the rows present in DF2 should be part of final df and from DF1 only those fields should be picked which have same value for id and key from DF2

Expected output:

```
+---------+--------------+----------------+----------+-------------------+
|id       |      key     |        tg      |created_at|          timestamp|       
+---------+--------------+----------------+----------+-------------------+
|device_id|    essentials|        template|1526472602|2020-10-15 19:08:05|
|device_id|    experiment|              c1|1727784602|2020-10-10 01:37:17|
|device_id|    experiment|              x1|1728994202|2020-10-19 01:37:17|
|device_id|    essentials|        template|1600269347|2020-09-21 19:08:05|
|device_id|    experiment|             t1|1599721314|2020-09-17 01:37:17|
|device_id|    experiment|             v1|1600228007|2020-09-21 18:07:53|
|device_id|    experiment|             c1|1605221085|2020-09-21 18:07:53|
|     test|            tk|               a|1728994202|2020-10-19 01:37:17|


+---------+--------------+----------------+----------+-------------------+


val intersection = df1
    .select("id", "key")
    .distinct
    .join(df2.select("id", "key").distinct, Seq("id", "key"))
df1.union(df2).join(intersection, Seq("id", "key")).show(false)

With this approach i am unable to get the last row shown in the example above
```

Comment: it is bit unclear. In note, you said rows from DF1 should be selected if it has same values for id and key as in DF2. If thats the case, then why row 4 & 5 from DF1 not included in expected answer. 
Or you meant to say same values for id, key and tg ?

Comment: Right 4 and 5 will be there, my bad. Have updated the question.

Comment: ok. I have updated my response answer to your query.

Answer (score 0):

Dataframe 1 - DF1
Dataframe 2 - DF2

```
DF2.union(DF1.as("DF1").join(DF2, Seq("id", "key"), "inner").select("id", "key", "DF1.tg", "DF1.created_at", "DF1.timestamp").distinct()).show()
```

Basically, you first select distinct rows from DF1 which matches the requirement via inner join, then union it with DF2 for expected answer.